# Which HTML tag should be used for short text?

Tags: html

I have the following markup on a web site footer

```
<div class="footer">
  Quick Links
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If I would wrap the Quick Links on an HTML tag which one would you use?

It seems a header of a section but being in the footer I wouldn't apply a H tag ...

I could use a p tag but is it a paragraph or should I use p for long text?

Maybe a div or a span?

Which tag do you think would be semantically correct?

Comment: I'd go for either a `<p>` or one of the lower `<hx>` elements.

Comment: ialarmed means something like `<h5>` or `<h6>`

Comment: Some interesting reading on headings from [the WCAG](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-GENERAL/H42.html) and web guru [Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2004/07/21/pick-a-heading/).

Comment: This is what the HMTL5 validator says about h1 - `"Consider using the h1 element as a top-level heading only (all h1 elements are treated as top-level headings by many screen readers and other tools)."` - It seems that semantics is not the only thing to consider.

Comment: @misterManSam Yes, that is one of the reason why I wouldn't use an H1 on the footer.

Comment: @MDMoura I voted to close this question as it really comes down to personal opinion. Interesting discussion though!

Comment: @misterManSam Agree. I just wanted some feedback and I though the answers would not be so opinion based.

Comment: @MDMoura - It's a shame that there is no objective answer :) Everyone has a different opinion and there are many conflicting "correct" answers. I think the answer by alien sums it up pretty well!

Answer (score 2):

I would go for one of the lower `h`*x* elements. Rationale: I will want it displayed as a block element, on top of the list; it is the header of a list, so an `hx` element would be suitable. However, it's not as important as the page title or headers in the page content, so it can use one of the lower ranked elements (the hierarchy of other elements in the page would also affect my choice of element--e.g. is there an `aside` element with a title? What does that use?). I would also swap out the `<div class="footer">` and use the html5 `<footer>` element:

```
<footer>
  <h4>Quick Links</h4>
  <ul>
    <li>Link one</li>
    <li>Link two</li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

For the most part, tag choice is really down to the individual. Do what you think is right!

A couple of links to related resources:

- [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines on headings](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-GENERAL/H42.html) (includes other useful links)
- [Eric Meyer on picking a heading!](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2004/07/21/pick-a-heading/)
- [The fiction of HTML 5 Outlines](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/10/html5-document-outline/)

Comment: Yes, I know sometimes is just a question of opinion ... In my opinion an h4 must be under a h3 to be semantic correct. No? So it is hard to preview what a footer will be under the web page structure.

Comment: Yes, I have footer tag ... When I wrote the question I forgot to write it as so.

Comment: @MDMoura Yes, there is that aspect to it--I don't like violating the hierarchy of H elements in a page but I would assign the footer header according to the relative importance of the content to the page. There are some schools of thought that each `<section>` (or `<header>`, `<footer>`, etc.) of the page should start with an `<h1>` element and work downwards, but I don't follow them. If you want to be completely non-controversial about it, you could just use a `<p>`!

Comment: I think this is the best answer we can get. Pick a heading for the footer that fits in with the rest of your markup and only use `h1` for your primary header to account for screen readers and other tools... and I agree with this the most `->"For the most part, tag choice is really down to the individual. Do what you think is right!"`. It all comes down to personal preference in the end!

Answer (score 0):

If its a header or at the top of webpage, go for nav. If for the bottom, footer is appropriate option.

```
<div class="footer">
  <nav>
    Quick Links
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```